# matlab Not enough input arguments error

Tags: matlab

I am brand new to matlab. I got an error that saying " Not enough input arguments"

```
function ckl = cofact(A,k,l)
% Cofactor ckl of the a_kl entry of the matrix A.
[m,n] = size(A);
if m ~= n
   error('Matrix must be square')
14
end
B = A([1:k-1,k+1:n],[1:l-1,l+1:n]);
ckl = (-1)^(k+l)*det(B);
```

error:

```
>> cofact
Error using cofact (line 3)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Comment: You defined that your function should have 3 input arguments, but you are calling it without any argument. Look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html for variable number of arguments. It is a bad practice in matlab to place functions and scripts in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Matlab you can have functions with input and output arguments. In your case you have both. The first one, "clk" is the output argument (solution). And your input arguments are "A","k","l". When you call your function "cofact"you need to call it by stablishing this arguments. 
Therefore you need to define the input value to variables "A","k","l". In your case A will be the matrix and k and l the positions you want to use. So when you call it, will be something simillar to:

solution=cofact(MATRIX,ARG1,ARG2);